# PayTM Merchant page is not rendering

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I'm trying to integrate `paytm merchant payment gateway`. To get the Payment page I have method

```
getCheckoutPage() {
    this.vendor.checkout(this.data.money, this.totalGST, this.TotalAmount).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);
        this.paymentButtonHtml = this.domSantizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(res);
      }
    );
  }
```

response is like below

**`response`**

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>
</head>
<body>
 <br>
 <br>
 <center><h1>Your transaction is being processed!!!</h1></center>
 <center><h2>Please do not refresh this page...</h2></center>
 <form method="post" action="https://securegw-stage.paytm.in/theia/processTransaction" name="f1" style="visibility: hidden;">
<table border="1">
<tbody>
<input type="hidden" name="REQUEST_TYPE"  value="DEFAULT" />
<input type="hidden" name="MID"  value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" />
<input type="hidden" name="ORDER_ID"  value="xxxxxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="CUST_ID"  value="426" />
<input type="hidden" name="INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"  value="Retail" />
<input type="hidden" name="CHANNEL_ID"  value="WAP" />
<input type="hidden" name="TXN_AMOUNT"  value="40.12" />
<input type="hidden" name="WEBSITE"  value="xxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="CALLBACK_URL"  value="http://api.xxxxxxxxx.com/api/payment/status" />
<input type="hidden" name="MOBILE_NO"  value="xxxxxxxxxx" />
<input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
</tbody>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.f1.submit();
</script>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and html is

```
 <p   [innerHTML]="this.paymentButtonHtml"></p>
```

but the page is always showing only

> Your transaction is being processed!!!
>   Please do not refresh this page...

after this is text the payment page is rendering. I'm stuck here from past 2 hours. could any one help me sove this problem. thanks in adavance